# jQuery Tools 1.2.6 Tabs - initialIndex + history options bug

Tags: jquery, tabs, history, jquery-tools

So, it seems that Tabs 1.2.6 has a bug when using initialIndex (to specify which tab to load on) and the history plugin. So:

```
$("ul#tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
        effect: 'fade',
        initialIndex: 3
    });
```

Works perfectly  and opens the 4th tab..... But, if I include this:

```
$("ul#tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
            effect: 'fade',
            initialIndex: 3,
            history: true
        });
```

The fourth tab is clicked and then immediately afterwards the first tab is engaged...

Has anyone run across this bug yet? If so, any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here's a fiddle:

Working with initialIndex
http://jsfiddle.net/xAmqj/1/

Not working with history (could be fiddle restricts the use of hash in their app as well)
http://jsfiddle.net/xAmqj/5/

ANOTHER UPDATE (11/02/2011):
Easiest solution I found was to keep the history option in, and take out the initialIndex option. Then before the script for tabs is even ran, place this as the very first script on your page:

```
window.location.hash = 'yourhashtag';
```

history will take care of the rest and will engage that tab. Didn't feel like adding a whole bunch of other code into history. Lazy... I know.. But it works.

Comment: Thanks for this work-around. There is a minor bug in your solution, which is if a user bookmarks the page (or emails the URL) with a different tab selected, then the default tab is loaded instead. Solution is to surround the line with if statement: `if (!window.location.hash) window.location.hash = 'yourhashtag';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually "history" working like "initialIndex", it take "hash" and set it as initialIndex of tabs, so its not a bug, it just you can't use both together.

If you look at JQuery tools documentation demos you can see that you can make any tab is starting tab "like" initial using hash:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.htm#streaming_tab

You can see that the initialIndex is third tab but without using "initialIndex", just using hash.

Your code problem is the tabs tools read initialIndex and select 4th tab, and then return "history" index that without hash means first tab, so that's it.

To be sure of that, put a hash href on second tab as example like `href="#sec_tab"` then add this hash "#sec_tab" on the end of your page url, you will see that 4th tab will shown (clicked) and then will moved to 2nd tab this time not first.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for the input. I was worried about that.. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't state anything about the two not working together.. Looks like I'm goning to have to code that in myself.. History should just be apart of tabs as an option, and there should be logic built in to allow both to exist... Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: @spez86 , yes, you are right, they must write it, but I think they think that is logically can't be together, but sometimes your business need that, try to post that in their forum.

Comment: Well, they theoretically could be... if initialIndex is presented in the options, then it should just fire that tab and append the hash to the page on load, while eliminating history's default action by going to the first tab... I guess I don't understand why history was created to be a separate tool, when it clearly should just be a part of the entire package..